# Kernel TCP tuning for buffer overrun and packet collapse

Tags: linux-networking, tcp, linux-kernel, netstat

We have a Nginx+Ruby application where the data between Nginx and the application are interfaced through a socket.

As part of performance improvement, when we analyzed the `netstat` statistics on the application side we saw these:

```
    5334 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun
    2299951 packets collapsed in receive queue due to low socket buffer
    227365 delayed acks sent
```

Assuming the `rmem` buffer capacity is the issue we find that:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_rmem
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380   6291456
```

However, looking at `cat /proc/net/protocols`:

```
protocol  size sockets  memory press maxhdr  slab module     cl co di ac io in de sh ss gs se re sp bi br ha uh gp em
PINGv6    1120      0      -1   NI       0   yes  ipv6        y  y  y  n  n  y  n  n  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n
RAWv6     1120      0      -1   NI       0   yes  ipv6        y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  n
UDPLITEv6 1280      0       3   NI       0   yes  ipv6        y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  n  n  y  y  y  n
UDPv6     1280      0       3   NI       0   yes  ipv6        y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  n  n  y  y  y  n
TCPv6     2152      4      52   no     256   yes  ipv6        y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y
PACKET    1408      0      -1   NI       0   no   kernel      n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n
UNIX      1024     24      -1   NI       0   yes  kernel      n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n
UDP-Lite  1088      0       3   NI       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n  n  y  y  y  n
PING       912      0      -1   NI       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  n  n  y  n  n  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n
RAW        920      0      -1   NI       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  n  n
UDP       1088      4       3   NI       0   yes  kernel      y  y  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  n  n  y  y  y  n
TCP       1992    209      52   no     256   yes  kernel      y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  y  n  y  y  y  y  y
NETLINK   1048      0      -1   NI       0   no   kernel      n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n  n
```

We see that there is no `memory pressure`.

We would like some advice along the following:

1. How can we find out if the buffer was actually overrun? Can we find out what the allocated buffer size was during a certain time period? Or what the maximum buffer size was? If the actual maximum buffer size was 6 MiB then we can assume the buffer was overrun.
2. If the buffer was overrun, why the `memory pressure` flag is not set? Does the `memory pressure` flag means that the system was not able to allocate the `minimum` buffer size?
3. Do `buffer overruns` and `packet collapses` always mean the socket buffer size was not enough?

Thank you.